# Google web font "Open Sans" does not show up in the correct weight if also installed locally on Windows 7+10

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, chromium, webfonts, google-webfonts

I am using "Open Sans" like so:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js"></script>
<script>
WebFont.load({
google: {
  families: ['Open+Sans:400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic:latin']
}
});
</script>
```

and all works as it should, except on 2 of my PCs (one with "Windows 7" and the other one with "Windows 10") with the most recent "Chrome Browser", there is no difference between the widths of 600 and 700. With the most recent "Edge" and "Firefox" browsers all is good.

I found out, that on both machines "Open Sans" was installed locally. On the "Windows 7" PC by myself and on the "Windows 10" PC it was already pre installed. After uninstalling the local font on both PCs all was working fine.

Is this some kind of a chrome bug?
<s>Could not find anything online about it.</s>

Also, if other users have on their "Windows 10" PCs "Open Sans" locally pre installed, then the website I am developing would show on a Chrome Browser also the wrong weights for the "Open Sans" font. Can this be somehow avoided?

PS1. not using any "src: local(..." declarations in my css

PS2. not importing fonts via @font-face instead using webfont.js to handle all

here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/x75h2624
as you can see on win10 / chrome Open Sans 600 + 700 (both only on normal not italic) is exactly the same. on win10 firefox, win10 edge, iOS chrome etc... all works OK!

PS3. just found this
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=335050
and posted there as well
could it be related and not fixed since 2014?

PS4. as this issue was quite old I filed a new bug report:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=617419
and also found this blog describing the same problem: http://timschreiber.com/2015/01/20/local-web-font-conflict-in-chrome/

Comment: find the CSS instruction that tries to load it locally first, and remove that entirely.

Comment: Just go to google fonts and use the link ref blabla version to import the font.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: not using any "src: local(..." declarations

Comment: @T04435: webfont.js takes care of everything, it is for this use case essential to use webfont.js instead of another solution. I quite not understand what you meant by your answer.

Comment: so a but necessary debugging step is to see what happens when you *don't* use webfont.js, but load the google fonts the way google fonts tells you - when you literally use the code that google gives you (config first, *then* dynamic script injection), does it work? If not, when you use a regular stylesheet import, do things work?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: indeed a couple of weeks ago I started with the normal HTML way, and now almost finished the page, started optimizing for PageSpeed and also using the same FLASH bevaviour on all browsers (I decided to go the FOUT way). no matter which of the 3 ways in T04435s answer I used, the problem persists.

Comment: then either you'll need to update  your POST to reflect your current code, or this question should probably be unasked because it's no longer technically related to what you're doing =)

Comment: you misunderstood me, it is the actual code up there and in the fiddle... i meant a couple of weeks ago it was pure html/css way, now it is webfont.js, and now i noticed the bug. but as i answered under T04435s answer, i just tried html/css way and this doesnt work either. please check the fiddle and you will see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was thinking, that in order to avoid this Chrome bug one has to be able to specify the "Open Sans" font family with a custom name, in order for Chrome not to get confused, so by reading carefully through the WebFontLoader specs under the heading "Custom" (https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader#custom) I was lucky, this is actually possible!

What I did was first downloading the needed **Fonts + CSS** from http://www.localfont.com/

After uploading the fonts to my server I added the downloaded CSS declarations into my own css file. **Beware:** remove all the **local('...')** declarations and rename all instances of **font-family: 'Open Sans';** to something custom, I chose **font-family: 'CustomOpenSans';**.

After this the css in my case looked like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'CustomOpenSans';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-regular/Open-Sans-regular.eot');
  src: url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-regular/Open-Sans-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-regular/Open-Sans-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-regular/Open-Sans-regular.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-regular/Open-Sans-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-regular/Open-Sans-regular.svg#OpenSans') format('svg');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'CustomOpenSans';
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-600/Open-Sans-600.eot');
  src: url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-600/Open-Sans-600.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-600/Open-Sans-600.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-600/Open-Sans-600.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-600/Open-Sans-600.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-600/Open-Sans-600.svg#OpenSans') format('svg');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'CustomOpenSans';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-700/Open-Sans-700.eot');
  src: url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-700/Open-Sans-700.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-700/Open-Sans-700.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-700/Open-Sans-700.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-700/Open-Sans-700.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-700/Open-Sans-700.svg#OpenSans') format('svg');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'CustomOpenSans';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
  src: url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-italic/Open-Sans-italic.eot');
  src: url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-italic/Open-Sans-italic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-italic/Open-Sans-italic.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-italic/Open-Sans-italic.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-italic/Open-Sans-italic.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-italic/Open-Sans-italic.svg#OpenSans') format('svg');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'CustomOpenSans';
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: italic;
  src: url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-600italic/Open-Sans-600italic.eot');
  src: url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-600italic/Open-Sans-600italic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-600italic/Open-Sans-600italic.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-600italic/Open-Sans-600italic.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-600italic/Open-Sans-600italic.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-600italic/Open-Sans-600italic.svg#OpenSans') format('svg');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'CustomOpenSans';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
  src: url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-700italic/Open-Sans-700italic.eot');
  src: url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-700italic/Open-Sans-700italic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-700italic/Open-Sans-700italic.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-700italic/Open-Sans-700italic.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-700italic/Open-Sans-700italic.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../assets/fonts/Open-Sans-700italic/Open-Sans-700italic.svg#OpenSans') format('svg');
}
```

and the webfont.js code like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
WebFontConfig = {
    custom: { families: [ 'CustomOpenSans' ] }
}; 
</script>
```

The line **custom** with the custom family naming did the trick.

Also I needed to change the **font-family** value in my CSS to **'CustomOpenSans'** like so:

```
body
{
    font-family: 'CustomOpenSans', sans-serif;
}
```

I am hoping the guys at Chromium will fix this issue soon...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the font as per Google font website instructions, I will also include the options for HTML, CSS as well as the **webfont.js**

#### HTML

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

#### CSS

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700);
```

#### JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  WebFontConfig = {
    google: { families: [ 'Open+Sans:400,600,700:latin' ] }
  };
  (function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
})();  
</script>
```

Thanks T04435.

Comment: thanks for the thorough answer, used the HTML way before switching to the way I described in my initial post (in order to optimize for PageSpeed and use FOUT for all browsers), but rechecked again with all 3 of your suggestions, and the problem persists

Comment: Have you try it in another computers but your, could you post a link to the site???

Comment: have tried on 3 pc's, two win10 one win7, all the same problem on chrome. as I explained, on win10 "Open Sans" was preinstalled and after uninstalling all was good. on the win7 pc I installed "Open Sans" myself, and then the problem appeared. again after uninstalling it, all worked. cannot give you access to the site, but will create a fiddle soon

Comment: here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/x75h2624/
as you can see on win10 / chrome Open Sans 600 + 700 (both only on normal not italic) is exactly the same. on win10 firefox, win10 edge, iOS chrome etc... all works OK!

Comment: just found this  
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=335050  
could it be related and not fixed since 2014?

Comment: as this issue was quite old, I filed also a new bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=617419 and also found this blog describing the same problem: http://timschreiber.com/2015/01/20/local-web-font-conflict-in-chrome/